# Are IEnumerable<T>, Task<T> and IDisposable hard coded in the C# compiler?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I asked that question myself many times. I tried to find some blog post about that and even dug into the Roslyn source code, but have not found any complete answer on that.

Basically, with some modern C# language features the compiler will take some syntactic sugar and transforms it into more low-level C# code. Some example of those are:

- `using()` generates a `try-finally` to definitely dispose an `IDisposable`
- Functions returning an `IEnumerable<T>` with `yield return` will turn that function into an iterator implemented as a state machine
- Functions marked with `async` have to return `Task<T>` (or similar) and will turn into a state machine too, which can be re-entered from the programs event-loop under the hood

So, these are all nice features, but the compiler is always enforcing the specific types `IEnumerable<T>`, `Task<T>` and `IDisposable`. **Are these types somehow baked into the compiler? And isn't it true that the compiler is somehow bound to the standard library then, even though `mscorlib` is just plain C# code providing common functionality?**

I cannot imagine that since programming languages are so abstract and general. As I have seen there is the possibility for `await`-ing anything as long as the type has an `GetAwaiter` extension method. That sounds more abstract to me.

**Edit**

Also, if anyone can point me to the source code which specifies the required predefined types in the compiler, let me know!

Comment: The compiler translates the code you wrote to code that uses the `IEnumerable<T>`,  `Task<T>` and `IDisposable` interfaces. The C# compiler is "binded" to mscorlib... Think if `typeof(x)` that returns a `Type` for example.

Comment: Yes, but still. Exactly these types have to be used. If not, the compiler throws an error. So are these types just defined by the compiler?

Comment: No. The types are defined in mscorlib. The C# compiler "knows" of these types.

Comment: The [C# Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/) describes the specific transformations that are required. Also, bear in mind that you *can* pass [`-nostdlib`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/nostdlib-compiler-option) as a compiler option, but then *you* have to provide an equivalent.

Comment: In general, no, they're not. The compiler needs `System.IDisposable` to be available in order to compile `using`, but it doesn't much care about the definition of `IDisposable` itself, so different `mscorlib`s can easily be swapped in. (`mscorlib` is *far* from "just plain C# code", however -- there's a lot of special glue living there that is not allowed in other assemblies.)

Comment: Note that there are at least two constructs (`foreach` and `await`) that use duck-typing and don't need specific types (you can pass anything that has a `GetEnumerator()` to `foreach`, and you can pass anything that has a `GetAwaiter ()` to `await`).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is interesting! Haven't head about it yet

Comment: Note that there's a definite drawback to being "more abstract" -- try implementing `ValueTuple` without actually being allowed to assume there is such a type. Not everything can be done by one duck typed method, so some integration between "well known types" and the compiler is almost inevitable.

Comment: In the end there are probably some tens of types that are defined in mscorlib and that are "known" by the C# compiler. Think about `System.Int32`, `System.String`, `System.Type`, `System.Delegate`, `System.MulticastDelegate`, `System.Object`, `System.ValueType`, `System.Enum`, `System.Array`, ...

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, you are right. Kinda eye opening

Comment: @BrunoZell For the edit, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/tree/master/spec) there are the C# specification. Note that there is no single complete table of all the used types. They are often named in the text, like *the direct base class of a class type must not be any of the following types: `System.Array`, `System.Delegate`, `System.MulticastDelegate`, `System.Enum`, or `System.ValueType`* . The documentation isn't even complete on this: the C# compiler introduces various attributes in the code (like `[CompilerGenerated]` for anonymous types) that aren't named in the specifications

Comment: That is a good and accurate mental model.  But isn't special, every language has a strong runtime implementation dependency.  What is so nice about C# is that it is all documented so well and generally usable.  Not something language implementers like to do, keeping it undocumented makes it a lot easier to change/improve it.  Microsoft did not do this for C#, they wanted to make it easy for everybody to create a compiler for their language of choice.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Where can I read more about `mscorlib` not being just plain C#?

Comment: Mostly in `mscorlib` itself, and also partially the ECMA CLI standards. For example, you can declare functions in `mscorlib` that use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` to call back into the runtime; attempting to declare and call such functions outside it will throw a `SecurityException`. Types like `Int32` are of course entirely special and are basically only present in `mscorlib` to give people something to reflect over; the compiler doesn't use them in "real" code. This is technically still all regular bytecode ("plain C#"), but it's not treated the same by the loader/JIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort-of.

The compiler has lists of "special" (used in the type-system / binder) and "well-known" (referenced by generated code) types and members, which are hard-coded by name in Roslyn source.  However, all that it cares about are the names & methods / signatures of these types / members; you can still write your own mscorlib (and people have done this) as long as it has them.

See

- http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/SpecialType.cs
- http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/SpecialMember.cs
- http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/WellKnownTypes.cs
- http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/WellKnownMemberNames.cs